# Hide Checkbox in Views Bulk Operations

Tags: views

I used Views Bulk Operations to modify entity values.
I chose  two fields/values to be displayed.

It works fine. But I wanted to remove the checkboxes(the checkboxes are used to choose what values you wanted to be displayed).

I want to automatically display the two fields. Since the other field is dependent to the other field.

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove VBO checkboxes from a view? Can you just remove the field?

Comment: Nope. Once you check the VBO checkbox in the views and click the `modify entity values` , you will go to another page wherein you can edit the values of the fields. In that page, you will see the fields you chose to display and their corresponding checkbox.  once you click the checkbox,  the field will appear.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean...